# Need to hide every 7th column in excel until AWZ column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a raelly big excel table where only every 7th column is relevant from column J. So I only want to see column J-Q-X-AE and so on until column AWZ. (Need to hide 6 columns in between.) Can anyone help? Unfortunately I am a beginnere at this.

Answer (score 1):

### Show Every Nth Column

**Initial Solution**

```
Option Explicit

Sub showEveryNthColumn()
    
    Const FirstColumn As String = "J"
    Const LastColumn As String = "AWX"
    Const EveryNthColumn As Long = 7
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim First As Long
        First = .Columns(FirstColumn).Column
        Dim Last As Long
        Last = .Columns(LastColumn).Column
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim j As Long
        For j = First To Last Step EveryNthColumn
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Columns(j))
            Else
                Set rng = .Columns(j)
            End If
        Next j
        .Columns.Hidden = True
        rng.Columns.Hidden = False
        .Columns("A:" &  FirstColumn).Hidden = False

        rng.Cells(1).Activate
    End With

End Sub
```

**With a Twist**

```
Sub showEveryNthColumnWithATwist()
    
    Const InitColumns As String = "A:K"
    Const FirstColumn As String = "Q"
    Const LastColumn As String = "AWX"
    Const EveryNthColumn As Long = 7
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim First As Long
        First = .Columns(FirstColumn).Column
        Dim Last As Long
        Last = .Columns(LastColumn).Column
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Columns(InitColumns)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = First To Last Step EveryNthColumn
            Set rng = Union(rng, .Columns(j))
        Next j
        .Columns.Hidden = True
        rng.Columns.Hidden = False
        .Columns(InitColumns).Cells(1).Activate
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it works, only problem is that it also hides column s from A to K, but I would need those.

Comment: @addressed OPs issue, hope you don't mind

Comment: @chrisneilsen: I think you didn't look close enough at the `With a Twist` solution. The lines `Const InitColumns As String = "A:K"` and `Set rng = .Columns(InitColumns)` are addressing OP's issue. I left the first solution as is, because that was the initial request: every 7th starting from column `J`, which may be useful for others.

Comment: @VBasic2008, ah yes, I see that now